# Rails convert date format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I have a form input in my application that accepts dates in the format DD/MM/YYYY eg 02/05/2012 is 2nd May 2012.

What is the best way for me to convert this into a suitable format to be added to the database through ActiveRecord?

Is there a simply way of converting 02/05/2012 to 05/02/2012 before adding to the database?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is similar to [Getting rails to accept European date format (dd/mm/yyyy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204992/getting-rails-to-accept-european-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy?rq=1)

In your model, create a setter method, where "my_date" is your database field.

```
def my_date=(val)
  Date.strptime(val, "%d/%m/%Y") if val.present?
end
```

Answer (score 5):

For this specific format you can call [`DateTime.parse`](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#M000528):

```
DateTime.parse("02/05/2012") # => Thu, 02 May 2012 00:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. When I do this with 19/05/2012 it does not work though. I think it's expecting date to be in MM/DD/YYYY, and there is no 19th month.

Comment: Works fine on my system. Maybe this depends on the locale.

Answer (score 3):

2 Years later but it's something I came across too, here's my fix.

In your view, use:
<%= l article.created_at, format: :euro %>  **make sure to add the l

And then in /config/locales/en.yml add:

```
en:

 time:

  formats:

    euro: "%d/%m/%Y"
```

** you can also just add, euro: "%D" to display in the us date format.

Thanks.