# Saving date field as dd/mm/yyyy rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, date

We have a `date_of_birth` field of `date` type in our `User` model.

When I am trying to save my User object.

```
u = User.last
u.date_of_birth = "31-03-1987"
u.save
```

results:

```
u.date_of_birth
=> Tue, 31 Mar 1987
```

but If I replace `-` with `/`

```
u.date_of_birth = "31/03/1987"
u.save
```

results:

```
u.date_of_birth
=> nil
```

**Question**

Is this is a default behaviour?

Or Am I missing something?

Comment: I'd recommend using ISO8601 formats (YYYY-MM-DD) except at the very edges of your application. Reformat on input and output but standard formats everywhere else. Not really an answer but it makes the problem go away by using unambiguous standard formats ;)

Comment: This is not a default behaviour of postgres. Postgres can save in both formats either DD-MM-YYYY or  DD/MM/YYYY .

Answer (score 0):

It will be set obviously nil because `date_of_birth` does not hold a valid format.

The standard DB format for datetime is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Using postgres db for higher rails version i.e. Rails 3+ you cannot get such issue,

```
>   u.created_at = '03/04/2017'
# => "03/04/2017" 
> u.created_at 
# => Mon, 03 Apr 2017 00:00:00 IST +05:30
```

Issue does exists in older version of ruby. I recommend you to either get updated or change format of string date input

Comment: Hi ritesh, thanks for your answer, I am aware of the format. But my exact question is about the delimiters, How are they affecting it?

Comment: @PraveshKhatri Issue is present for lower version of ruby refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26310126/10522579)